# Using sed with herestring (<<<) and read -a

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, read

I use `sed` with `<<<` and `read` to assign all words in a string to variables. What I do is:

```
read -a A0 <<< $(sed '2q;d' /proc/stat)
```

Hence, `sed` reads the second line of the file `file` and immediately quits. The line `sed` has read in is fed to `<<<` which does expands the input it receives from `sed` and `read -a` assign the resulting values of `<<<` to elements of an array. Is the usage of `<<<` and `sed` in this way a good idea or are there obvious reasons that speak against this and most of all, is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array assignment directly:

```
A0=($(sed '2q;d' /proc/stat))
```

Beware that this performs globbing: if the output of the command contains shell wildcards, then the words containing wildcards are replaced by the list of matching files if there are any. If the output of the command might contain one of the characters `\[?*`, temporarily turn off globbing:

```
set -f
A0=($(sed '2q;d' /proc/stat))
set +f
```

This can be tiny faster than using `read`:

```
$ time for i in {1..1000}; do read -a A0 <<< $(sed '2q;d' /proc/stat); done

real    0m2.829s
user    0m0.220s
sys     0m0.480s

$ time for i in {1..1000}; do A0=($(sed '2q;d' /proc/stat)); done

real    0m2.388s
user    0m0.128s
sys     0m0.276s
```

With `bash` 4.0 and above, you can use `mapfile`:

```
mapfile -t < <(sed '2q;d' /proc/stat)
```

But `mapfile` seems to be slowest:

```
$ time for i in {1..1000}; do mapfile -t < <(sed '2q;d' /proc/stat); done

real    0m3.990s
user    0m0.104s
sys     0m0.444s
```

Comment: Asking a personal opinion here but only in a comment: Would you use array assignment directly or rather `mapfile`? (Why did I not think of direct array assignment???)

Comment: @lord.garbage: I will use direct assignment, see my updated.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax seems too complex to my eyes. I'd use the following instead:

```
read -a A0 < <( sed '2q;d' /proc/stat )
```

I usually use the `<<< word` syntax when I need a command to take input from a variable, not from another command.

Comment: Gives me only an error so far.

Comment: @lord.garbage: Sorry, missing character. Fixed now.